# ODI Oracle Interfaces

Tags: oracle, interface

I'm actually working on a datawarehouse ( ODI ) that contains several scenario which contains so many interfaces , the problem is 
that some of interfaces are related by some tables while execution, how can I find tables related to each interface in the scenario?
In an other way: I have an interface which references so many tables and I need to be able to select the name of these tables?

Comment: What is your definition of an "interface"?  Is an "interface" a view?  Is an "interface" the set of queries that a particular Oracle user executes?  Is it something else?

Comment: An integration interface is an Oracle Data Integrator object stored that enables the loading of one target datastore with data transformed from one or more source datastores, based on declarative rules implemented as mappings, joins, filters and constraints. I need to see all tables related to each interface .

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces in ODI give a visual/ diagrammatic interpretation of scripts that show how a target table is updated (insert/delete/update) using one or more source tables ( containing various joins and filters).
Then in ODI, there are packages which constitute several interfaces to be executed in an orderly fashion.
Then there are scenarios which are nothing but the executable files of each packages. While you run a batch in your warehouse, these scenarios are executed for actual data loading (ETL) process.

So coming to your question, you can only view what tables are being used in an interface by viewing the interface in ODI. If you want all tables in an scenario, locate the package of that scenario first, then open the package to find out interfaces, and open the interfaces to find out all tables, I am afraid that is the only way if you want it with ODI.

On the other hand these interfaces and packages are actually some script files in the back-end, to view the information through the back-end (in the server) depends entirely on what kind of back-end system you are using for data warehousing

Answer (score 0):

ODI Projects and models are stored as xml files for ease of source controlling. These files can be generated from within the ODI studio by using the [Export](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/integrate.1111/e12643/export_import.htm) functionality.

Once these files are generated, to migrate the ODI code between systems, the files have to be imported to a different ODI installation. When these files are imported, xml information is parsed and stored into relevant tables in the ODI Master repository.

Thus, the information that you are looking for can even be located from the ODI Master repository provided you know which [SNP_% table](http://sonra.io/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/RWhitepaper.pdf) you need to look for. If that is not your cup of tea, I would suggest visually checking for the tables as mentioned above.

Hope this helps.